# VBA delete rows that offset eachother

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to eliminate line items that cancel each other out.

For example, below the two rows that add to zero would be deleted (i.e., 87.1 and -87.1).

```
-87.1

890

87.1

898989
```

The code that I am using mostly works but in cases where there are numerous lines with the same values it is deleting all of them instead of just one matching value per observation. For example, below, I would want it to cancel out two of the -87.1s and two of the 87.1s but one would be leftover because there is no number directly offsetting it.

```
-87.1

890

87.1

898989

87.1

-87.1

-87.1
```

---

```
Sub x()
    Dim n As Long, rData As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    n = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("AV2:AV" & n).Formula = "=IF(I2=0,0,COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$" & n & ",C2,$I$2:$I$" & n & ",-I2))"

    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Rows(1).AutoFilter field:=48, Criteria1:=">0"
        With .AutoFilter.Range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rData Is Nothing Then
                rData.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
Sub DeleteOppositeNumbers()
    Dim Fnd As Range, r As Long
    'By: Abdallah Ali El-Yaddak
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Loop through the column bottom to top.
    For r = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(r, 3).Value > 0 Then 'If the value is positive
            'Sreach for it's opposite
            Set Fnd = Columns(3).Find(-Cells(r, 3).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole) 
            'If found, delete both.
            If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then Rows(r).Delete: Fnd.EntireRow.Delete 
        End If
    Next
    'Just to restore normal behaviour of sreach
    Set Fnd = Columns(3).Find(Cells(3, 2).Value, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Something Simpler:

```
Sub x()

Dim ar() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AV2:AV" & n).Formula = "=IF(I2=0,0,COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$" & n & ",C2,$I$2:$I$" & n & ",-I2))"

ar = ActiveSheet.Range("AV2:AV" & last).Value

For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)

        For j = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
            If i <> j Then

                If ar(i, 1) = ar(j, 1) Then

                ar(i, 1) = ""
                ar(j, 1) = ""

                End If
            End If
        Next

Next

For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)

   ActiveSheet.Range("AV" & i + 1).Value = ar(i, 1)

Next

ActiveSheet.Range("AV2:AV" & last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlUp

End Sub
```

I have tried and tested this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

        For i = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
            For j = UBound(arr) - 1 To LBound(arr) Step -1
                If arr(i, 1) + arr(j, 1) = 0 Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                    .Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```